# Is there a way to take Flash updates out of the hands of Adobe?

Tags: macos, safari, adobe-flash, adobe

I swore off Flash for a long while, until the great Safari support in Mavericks. Now I use it without fear.

However, the updating is always a pain. It seems like when I go to certain websites the "Adobe Flash Player Install Manager" fires up and bugs me to update. I don't want to have to think about doing these Flash updates all of the time.

Is there a way to stay up-to-date while not having this app bother me all of the time?

Comment: Google Chrome should do the trick. If you don't want to switch over from Safari, just remove Flash from your system, and keep Chrome for sites with Flash. Chrome auto updates itself and is always on the latest version of Flash.

Comment: Good thing you didn't leave that as an answer as I would have voted it down. :)

Comment: What is wrong with your Adobe player Auto update feature?

Answer (score 1):

While far from a perfect solution, you could run [this script from Rich Trouton](https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/tree/master/rtrouton_scripts/install_latest_adobe_flash_player) on a regular basis to install updates.

Note that the current version of the Flash player is 15, so you'd need to update the script's fileURL entry for this to download and install the correct .dmg.